# Distance metric between 2 integers and between 2 sets of integers with weights

Tags: distance, metric, weighted-data

I have several positive integer numbers representing the count of features, for example `delay`, `successful_attempts`, `failed_attempts`. Say I have 2 sets of such numbers, `A` and `B`:

```
A : delay=63, successful_attempts=6, failed_attempts=7
B : delay=84, successful_attempts=5, failed_attempts=12
```

I am trying to find a metric to use in order to find how each feature counter between `A` and `B` differs. That is, a metric which will compare the `delays` of `A` and `B` and give a number representing their **distance**. Similarly for the other two feature counters.

And finally, deduce a **total difference** of how similar the counters between `A` and `B` are, ideally via a **percentage** and with the option -if possible- of adding **weights** to each feature.

I have searched for such metrics but could not find anything; probably cause I was not searching correctly, I was getting hits for string comparison mainly.

I have considered the *Euclidean Distance* and the *Absolute* distance but would appreciate if someone could confirm if these are the appropriate metrics to use for my case and/or let me know of any other metrics more suitable. Also, a small example applying that metric in my case to better understand would be great.